# Can I use the controller of an external hard disk to connect a SSD to a USB port?

Tags: usb, ssd, external-hard-drive, sata

Can I use a 2.5" Intel SSD with the USB SATA adapter from a My Password external drive?

The adapter looks like this:

[image: http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v258/vindicator_5/Picture8.jpg]

Has anyone tried it? Did it explode?

Comment: No reason it wouldn't work - but that USB 2.0 interface would be a bottleneck

Answer (score 1):

It will not explode. As long as your SSD fits into that boatd (which it will) then you can start using it. No issues there. But, as a commenter said, your SSD will be slow since that's a USB2.0 connection.

Answer (score 0):

I've done exactly that with the USB adapter harvested from a WD Passport - looks just like the one in your picture. Well, it wasn't an *Intel* SSD... but, sure, it should work. As others have mentioned, the USB 2.0 bus will be the bottleneck.